# Managing nan when inserting a pandas DataFrame with sqlalchemy executemany

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, nan, executemany

I'm trying to insert a pandas dataframe into a mysql database using the *sqlalchemy* cursor's method `executemany`. It's a fast and efficient way to bulk insert data but there is no way to insert `pandas.NA`/`numpy.nan`/`None` values without having a `MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError` or `MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError`.

```py
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

def insert(dff, table_name):
    engine = create_engine('mysql://user:password@host:port/database?charset=utf8'), echo=False)

    # The query without the values to insert
    query_template = """
    INSERT INTO %s (%s)
    VALUES (%s)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE %s;
    """ % (
        table_name,
        ",".join(["`%s`" % colname for colname in dff.columns]),
        ','.join(['%s'] * len(dff.columns)),
        ",".join(["`%s`=VALUES(`%s`)" % (colname, colname) for colname in dff.columns])
    )

    # Connection and bulk insert
    with engine.begin() as connection:
        raw_connection = connection.engine.raw_connection()
        mycursor = raw_connection.cursor()
        mycursor.executemany(query_template, dff.values.tolist())  # /!\ Here is the problem /!\
        raw_connection.commit()
    engine.dispose()

dff = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ["a", "b", "c", "d"], "col2": [1, pd.NA, 2, 3], "col3": [0.0, 1, pd.NA, 3.43]})
insert(dff, "my_table")
```

I could probably precompute every queries or a big query by iterating over the DataFrame content but it would be a very inefficient way to work. Using the pandas DataFrame `to_sql` method would lack of flexibility when fine tunning `ON DUPLICATE KEY` so it isn't an option.

What would be the most efficient way to perform a pandas DataFrame bulk insert with a custom query and nan values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real problem is that `dff.values` create a typed matrix whom can't countained `None` values for *int* or *float*. But in reality the executemany can insert `None` values.

The fastest solution I've found is to correct the list of lists given to `executemany` instead of correcting the dataframe content before creating the list of lists.

My inserted data aren't `dff.values.tolist()` anymore but:

```py
inserted_data = [
    [None if pd.isnull(value) else value for value in sublist] \
    for sublist in dff.values.tolist()]

mycursor.executemany(query_template, inserted_data )
```